# Location services behaving weird

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to detect location services are enabled or not and based on that I want to enable or disable the button in my app. For that I have written

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
 // Enable button
else 
 // Disbale button
```

But, I found a strange behaviour with this method. From Settings,

1) If I turns location services OFF, for all apps than above method returns NO.(As expected)

2) If I turns locationServices ON, But OFF for my particualr app, than it returns YES.

Is this the correct behaviour. If yes, than is there any other method to find whether location services are enabled or disbaled at app level. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `locationServicesEnabled` method to find whether the location services are enabled for your app or not, I would like to clear that `locationServicesEnabled` detect whether the location services are enabled for the device or not. It does not check for particular application.

From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW4) *It returns a Boolean value indicating whether location services are enabled on the device*

You may use `locationManager:didFailWithError:` to detect the location services for the particular app

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW4)

### If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a kCLErrorDenied error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([[error domain] isEqualToString: kCLErrorDomain] && [error code] == kCLErrorDenied) {
        // Location Services are denied.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [`authorizationStatus`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus) property of `CLLocationManager` to see whether your application is authorised to access location information -

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && (CLLoctionManager.authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)) {
  // Enable button
}
else {
  // Disable button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
+(BOOL)checkLocationService {

    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        return NO; //location service disabled
    else if(kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized!=[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
        return NO; //app's location service disabled
    return YES;
}
```